# QGIS projects - collaboration on different platform

Tags: qgis, ubuntu, file-path, windows-8

On my computer, I have both  - Ubuntu and Windows - operating systems.
Since I work on both of them and QGIS save path to particular layers using absolute path, it's very inconvenient to store projects on local disk.

Moreover, I wish to access QGIS projects and layers from other computers.
Is there any possibility to store them on the Internet?
What will be the best, free of charge, solution?
I thought about Dropbox, but I'm not sure if there's more convenient way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Project Settings, you can specify if absolute or relative paths should be used. Dropbox can be a good solution if your files don't grow too big for the free data plan. If you provide more information about your requirements, we might be able to offer different solutions.

Comment: Store relative path is one of described issue. What about different OS? They use both "/" and "\" as location separator. Will it be a source of next problems?